Tact: Error when transferring coins between wallets - What am I doing wrong?
I've been trying to write a simple contract in Tact to transfer coins from one wallet to another. The goal is to send a specified amount of coins to a fixed wallet address whenever a MyMessage message is received. However, the code doesn't seem to work as expected, and I can't figure out what might be causing the issue.
Here's the code I wrote:
import "@stdlib/deploy";

message MyMessage {
    value: Int;
}

contract SendCoins with Deployable {
    deployer: Address;
    receiver: Address = address("0QBeVx8QwFKs-...."); 

    init() {
        self.deployer = sender();
    }
 
    receive(msg: MyMessage) {
        send(SendParameters{
            to: self.receiver,    // Send to the fixed wallet address
            bounce: true,
            value: msg.value,        // The specified amount is sent
            mode: 3,              // Mode 3 ensures proper transfer of the specified amount
            body: "Hello, World!".asComment(), // not necessary, can be omitted
        });
    }

    get fun balance(): String {
        return myBalance().toCoinsString();
    }
}

I would appreciate any insights into the following:

Am I using the send function correctly?
Is there anything wrong with the receive function or the way I'm handling the message?
Should I be concerned about using mode: 3 for sending the amount?

Any guidance on debugging this issue or suggestions for changes to make it work would be greatly appreciated.
Here's the code 2 I wrote:

import "@stdlib/deploy";

message Withdraw {
    amount: Int;
    message: String;
}

contract SendCoins with Deployable {

    const MinTonForStorage: Int = ton("0.01"); // 2.5 yıl boyunca 1 KB depolama için yeterli
    deployer: Address;
    receiver: Address = address("0QBeVx8QwFKs-....");

    init() {
        self.deployer = sender();
    }

    // Belirli bir miktarı çekerken 0.01 bırakır
    receive(msg: Withdraw) {
        //require(sender() == self.deployer, "Only deployer is allowed to withdraw");

        //let amount: Int = min(msg.amount, myBalance() - self.MinTonForStorage);
        //require(amount > 0, "Insufficient balance");

        send(SendParameters{
            to: self.receiver, // Sabit cüzdan adresine gönderim yapılıyor
            bounce: true,
            value: msg.amount, // Belirlenen miktar gönderiliyor
            mode: 3,  // Gelen tüm değeri gönder
            body: msg.message.asComment(), // not necessary, can be omitted
        });
    }

    get fun balance(): String {
        return myBalance().toCoinsString();
    }
}

